# How much time will it take to build Android OS

Tags: android

I was trying to build the Android operating system for Galaxy Nexus. It took 6 hours to build. Is it normal or does it have to do with my machine(MBP Core2Duo) or am I missing something?

Comment: This is probably offtopic here.

Comment: My understanding is that "hours" is a reasonable unit of measure for AOSP builds on ordinary hardware.

Comment: I built AOSP on a machine similar to that (4GBs RAM) it took about 2 hours. (The machine was a fresh install of Ubuntu, with nothing except build requirements.)

Comment: Some hints can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1812253).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is bit of a memory bound operation.
Next time you compile try using more threads

```
make -j8
```

or

```
make -j16
```

With 12 GB of memory I was able to compile the android source in like 40 mins.